# Does Android Things Support RenderScript Compute?

Tags: android-things, android-renderscript

I know that Android Things supports the NDK. I cannot find a reference that states, one way or another, whether Android Things supports RenderScript Compute. My assumption is no (on the grounds that not all Things platforms will have a suitable GPU), but I was hoping perhaps that people had tried it or otherwise know whether RenderScript Compute works on Android Things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My assumption is no (on the grounds that not all Things platforms will have a suitable GPU)

I'll be more specific when I know what a *"suitable" GPU* is, but if there are some of those (see below) among the supported [hardware platformes](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms) the assumption isn't correct.

> but I was hoping perhaps that people had tried it or otherwise know whether RenderScript Compute works on Android Things.

I tried [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RenderScriptIntrinsic/) on a *RPi3* and it worked, although the question if the computation was parallelized across both CPU **and GPU** left open.

[image]

Comment: Android Things support RenderScript. But for most of the IoT devices, maybe a GPU RenderScript driver is missing, and the compute will be parallelized using multi-core CPU as Onik said.

Comment: @CommonsWare Android Things support RenderScript, but probably running on CPU.